# Configure commands for using mysqlnd

Tags: php, iis-7, mysqli

The php.net page here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php says this

> Configure commands for using mysqlnd // Recommended, compiles with
>   mysqlnd $ ./configure --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
>   --with-mysql=mysqlnd

The question is where you enter this? How do you configure PHP? I'm using Windows IIS 7 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're following the wrong link.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php#mysql.installation.windows - here is an instructions for windows